# Electrically loaded resistive Potentiometer!

Tags: potentiometer, loading-effect

According to my course book, **Potentiometers produce a linear output as a function of displacement, provided that the potentiometer is not electrically loaded!**, **what is** **electrically loaded???**, mean in this context! Looking for a simple and straight forward answer!

Comment: Easy on the ? and ! and bolface, this reads like you are shouting. And better make the title a true question, now it seems more like a cry of dispair.

Comment: Thahahaha!! sorry for that, that was never my intension !! the bolds are just to high light the important message!

Comment: Again: why five ! in three sentences? We can read you loud and clear with just a . as terminator.

Comment: Ok, i will keep that in mind next time i reply. That is a bad habit i got from social medias.

Comment: @HiltonKhadka <smh>

Comment: why <smh> ?    @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Social media reference - shaking my head.

Comment: Oh, i was just curious why <smh>, is it because the way of asking questions seems wrong?

Comment: Not all potentiometers are linear: logarithmic pots (and anti-log) are available too. [Why should I use a logarithmic pot for audio applications?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101191/36731)

Answer (score 5):

It means that the wiper should only be connected to circuits that offer a high impedance such as the non-inverting input of an op-amp. Imagine you had a 10k resistor set half way across a 10V supply. The output would be 5V - now put a fixed 5k resistor from wiper to ground and the wiper voltage drops to 3.333V.

Answer (score 3):

Consider  voltage divider as follows, where a represents the pot shaft electrical rotation from 0 (fully CCW) to 1 (fully CW):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbCXQO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the pot is assumed to be perfectly linear so that the resistance of the bottom section of the pot varies from 0 to R ohms as a varies from 0 to 1, and the top section varies in the opposite direction from R to 0. I've also ignored the wiper series resistance for simplicity, but it's easy to take account if if you want.

I've attached a load resistor to ground RL. It should be easy to see that at either end the load resistor will make no difference to the output voltage. However when a is between the ends, a lower resistance at RL will reduce the voltage available at the wiper (and therefore across RL). I've plotted the curve for a 10K pot with 1K, 5K, 10K and 1M load resistance:

[image]

For example, with a 10K load, the output voltage will be 0.4V, not 0.5V, a 20% difference.